# Instantly redirect Audio Input to Audio Output

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb-audio

I am working with a headless flavor of linux and I am stumped when trying to handle some audio workings. I purchased a USB dongle to use which has a pink Audio in, and a green audio out 3.5mm jack. I am trying to process the sounds that are going in, then send the raw audio source right back out through the output.

Basically in the diagram I am trying to have audio going in, then instantly redirect it to the audio out. **How would I redirect the Audio Input to go to the Audio output of the same USB adapter?**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific low level raspberry pi hardware manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't specify which audio stack you use, there are a few options. If you are using PulseAudio, then the easiest software method is to [start the loopback module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403416/how-to-listen-live-sounds-from-input-from-external-sound-card) (first answer): run `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1` and set the source to your loopback. I'm fairly sure that ALSA [requires a loopback module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895216/how-to-route-pulse-audio-device-into-alsa-loopback-virtual-microphone), after which you can set the source to the loopback.

Personally however, I would skip the software solution and get a hardware splitter (an example is [this item on Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Mobi-Splitter-Headphone-Microphone-Adapter/dp/B06XPJBCQ8)) or a mixer (even a little 4-channel would be fine.) You will have no latency on the input, it lessens the load on the computer, and it works even if the computer is off. Actually, a mixer would probably be best for your application because then you can control the amount of input from your source audio and computer, and there's less likelihood of ground loops, etc.

Comment: That is what I currently am using, the headphone splitter, but the only issue that I have is when I turn up the phone to increase the volume on the speaker, it also increased the audio going into the RPI which destroys all the possible data. Is there something that exists to where I can control the volume of each invididual output (is that what a cheap mixer would do or is there some other alternative)

Comment: I'd go with the mixer option personally, as you'll have more control over matching line levels (it sounds like this is the case.) Depending on your budget, there are [digital mixers](https://www.amazon.ca/Mackie-ProFX8v2-8-Channel-Professional-Mixer/dp/B00VUU77XW?th=1&psc=1&source=googleshopping&locale=en-CA&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_22ivam2i1r_e) which get rid of the need for the line input completely. Check with your local music store because they'll have some ideas for your specific setup.